# How to create a List Dynamically by accepting classname

Tags: java, arraylist, hql

I am new to Java language. I have a case there I want to create a list dynamically.
e.g.

```
 public List getData(String classname)
{
   List<classname> ob = querywithParams.list();
    return ob;
 }
```

I will call this function like

```
List<Student> ob=getData("Student");
```

How can achieve this thing in Java?  I need this for creating a common DB Adapter for HQL execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T>  List<T> getData(String classname, Class<T> pClass)
    {
       List<T> ob = querywithParams.list();
        return ob;
     }
```

I don't see you using the `string classname` in your method so you might as well remove it (If you wanted that just to specify the class type). 
So if you remove the string param, an example invocation would of the form :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T>  List<T> getData(Class<T> pClass)
{
   List<T> ob = querywithParams.list();
    return ob;
 }

// example invocation from some other method
    List<Student> ob = getData(Student.class);
```

Comment: where are you using the classname?

Comment: @Scorpion ..List<Student> ob=getData("Student");Here Student is class name

Comment: @vmb : look at the edited answer, your method param needs to be of type class to infer the type rather than String

Comment: @Scorpion..its working..i will test it thoroughly and will mark as answer